# Customize T4 template - ADO.Net Entity data model for EF code first from existing database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net, t4, odp.net

I am trying to locate and customize the T4 template of ADO.Net Entity data model for EF code first from existing database.

What I want to customize or change is data type mapping. I am using Oracle's ODP.Net provider which supports EF. I am trying to remap the Oracle data type number to Int64 instead of Decimal due to my requirement.

As I am new to editing T4 files for customization I am finding difficulty in locating the template file that does the code first mapping. Any help in pointing me to the right direction is appreciated.[image]

Comment: Have you found something? As far as I searched, it's being generated by DLL and not by a T4. Found C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplatesCache\CSharp\Data\1033\CFCSEF6\CodeFirst_CS_V6.0.vstemplate  -> which led me to 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.dll ... but couldn't yet find the exact code.

Comment: @drizin no luck yet. Please let me know if you find any alternate solution.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE Feb 2017:** You should check out this amazing [EntityFramework Reverse POCO Code First Generator](https://github.com/sjh37/EntityFramework-Reverse-POCO-Code-First-Generator) project which consists of  **T4 templates to do Code First from an Existing Database**.

Those templates are very easy to use, fully customizable, and I could easily add my customizations to those templates! Not to mention that they are much more complete than the original EF wizard. The authors/contributors of that project are very friendly and responsive, and I have myself made a few contributions.

_

(Turns out that I was reinventing the square wheel by creating my own T4 templates).

**Original Answer** (just for reference if helps anyone digging into EF Wizard source code):

I don't know why, but the templates for Model First (**EF Designer from database**) are easily customizable (but they are EDMX based), while the code for **Code First from Database** is not that easy - even if you manage to find the templates.

If you right click your project, click "Entity Framework" and "Customize Reverse Engineer Templates" you will get `Context.tt`, `Entity.tt` and `Mapping.tt` inside folder `CodeTemplates\ReverseEngineerCodeFirst`. **However**, those templates need to be called by some external caller which should pass some context information to the templates - that's why they are not ready-for-customization as the Model First templates are.

Those are the same templates that you will find in [Entity Framework source code](https://github.com/Icehunter/entityframework.git) (in folder [`src\PowerTools\CodeTemplates\ReverseEngineerCodeFirst`](https://github.com/Icehunter/entityframework/tree/master/src/PowerTools/CodeTemplates/ReverseEngineerCodeFirst)). And in [`\src\PowerTools\Handlers\ReverseEngineerCodeFirstHandler.cs`](https://github.com/Icehunter/entityframework/blob/master/src/PowerTools/Handlers/ReverseEngineerCodeFirstHandler.cs) you will find the method `ReverseEngineerCodeFirst` that reads the metadata from the database and passes to those templates. That caller method can be copied into its own T4 template (so you don't need to build that Power Tools and install in your Visual Studio), but it has some interaction with Visual Studio and with the Project, which would be hard to do with plain T4 templates.

I created a [T4 template](https://gist.github.com/Drizin/161e5023297a15422dfb20f89f7a5b6b) based on that method mentioned above, basically by putting together all classes/helpers that the `ReverseEngineerCodeFirstHandler.cs` needs, and removing references to the Visual Studio DTE. There are some instructions on my template, but basically you should remove the include for `EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude`, and comment out the variables "var efHost" and "var code"

Those templates that you will find in folder `CodeTemplates\ReverseEngineerCodeFirst` are **almost identical** to the Code First From Database wizard, except for some minor differences:

- The wizard creates one-to-many navigation properties as `HashSet<T>`, while the templates creates those as `List<T>`
- The wizard uses nullables like `int?` while the other uses `Nullable<int>`
- The wizard adds some code-analysis suppression attributes `[SuppressMessage]`
- The wizard creates the DbSets as virtual, while the templates don't.
- The wizard generates part of the mappings using Data Annotations (like `[Table]`, `[Key]`, `[StringLength]`, etc) and the other parts (properties and relationships) inside `DbContext.OnModelCreating`. The T4 templates generate all mappings inside configuration classes for each entity (`EntityTypeConfiguration<Entity>`).

Most of those differences can be easily adjusted, although I don't think it really matters. If you want to make strong customizations (like I did on my templates, which include automatic infer of non-existing relationships, relationships to views, class inheritance), I suggest that you create your own DTOs (or POCOs) for passing Entities/Properties/NavigationProperties to the included templates. In my case I use the original `EdmMapping`, map it into my DTOs, make a lot of modifications on those DTOs (based on my company standards), and pass those DTOs to the T4 includes (with small modifications).